# Issue in accessing Bing Custom Web Search API v7

Tags: javascript, azure-cognitive-services, bing, bing-api, bing-search

I am trying to access the Bing Custom Search [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-custom-search/reference/query-parameters). Custom Search Instance is setup and able to call API from BING portal (production tab), however when I am trying to access the same URL through JS. I am getting Failed Request as below

[image]

Below is the way I am accessing the API:

```js
const query = "app";
const url = `https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/custom/search?q=${query}&customconfig=<CUSTOM_CONFIG_ID>&mkt=zh-CN`;
const option = {
  mode: "cors",
  headers: {
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": <Subsription Key>
  }
};

fetch(url, option)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I am getting error

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Find `CUSTOM_CONFIG_ID` in https://www.customsearch.ai/ .
2. Find `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` on portal.

[image]

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const query = "app";
const url = `https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/custom/search?q=${query}&customconfig=<CUSTOM_CONFIG_ID>&mkt=zh-CN`;
const option = {
    mode: "cors",
    headers: {
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": '<Subsription Key>'
    }
};

fetch(url, option)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((err) => console.log("err: " + err));
```

**My Test Result:**

*Please run `node install node-fetch` first.*

[image]